# Asp.net core 2.1 UseHttpsRedirection not working in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I deployed my asp.net core 2.1 WebApi to IIS 10. (The IIS worked as a proxy)

I have added a SSL cert in IIS and bindings for both insecure port (8081) and secure port (8082).

But when I visit http://localhost:8081/api/values, the browser just return me 403 Forbidden, not redirect me to https://localhost:8082/api/values.

My StartUp Code is as below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
           .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options=>
        {
            options.HttpsPort = 8082;
        });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

The issue I found was that a change from .net core 2.0 to .net core 2.1 meant that the https port needed to be specified explicitly in startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });
```

See here for more info: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3176

Comment: Hi, I have this issue and I changed my port to 443, but it doesnot resolve the issue. Do you please have another alternative ?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the error was that I was calling things in an unsupported order. By rearranging my code to first call:

```
app.UserHttpsRedirection()
```

and then call

```
app.UseHsts()
```

it started to work instead of the other way around.

Comment: This works but it is strange because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#usehttpsredirection) shows incorrect order.

Answer (score 2):

In my startup.cs i made this settings

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    try
    {
        //..other codes

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.HttpsPort = 443;
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string innerMessage = "";
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            innerMessage = ex.InnerException.Message;

        Log.Logger.Error("ConfigureServices Message: " + ex.Message + " inner Message:" + innerMessage + "Env.Name:" + _env.EnvironmentName);
    }
}
```

And in the Configure method, i used like this

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You received this status code because you have selected Require SSL in SSL Settings.

[image: IIS - SSL Settings]

[image: IIS - SSL Settings]

If you want to use your code to redirect to https unchecked this option.

But first you should read carefully documentation: [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

> Do not use RequireHttpsAttribute on Web APIs that receive sensitive
>   information. RequireHttpsAttribute uses HTTP status codes to redirect
>   browsers from HTTP to HTTPS. API clients may not understand or obey
>   redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. Such clients may send information over
>   HTTP. Web APIs should either:
>
> - Not listen on HTTP.
> - Close the connection with status code 400 (Bad Request) and not serve the request.

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Comment: Thank you! 60 minutes of chasing my tail.